# How to plot a parametric 3d surface in bokeh

Tags: bokeh

I want to draw a 3d surface with bokeh. I noticed that I can draw surfaces like z = f(x, y), but I was not able to draw parametric surface like f(x,y,z) = 0. In which the later can be closed surface. I appreciate your help.
here is [the link](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions_gallery/wrapping.html#userguide-extensions-examples-wrapping) to example. I included here the change I have made in the example not the whole code.

```
# parametric torus as an example in which the equation for the surface can be rephrased to be like f(x,y,z) = 0
angle = np.linspace(0, 2. * np.pi, 30)
theta, phi = np.meshgrid(angle, angle)
r, R = .25, 1.
xx = (R + r * np.cos(phi)) * np.cos(theta)
yy = (R + r * np.cos(phi)) * np.sin(theta)
xx = xx.ravel()
yy = yy.ravel()
value = r * np.sin(phi)
value = value.ravel()

# here is the original example which draw a surface like Z = f(x,y)
"""
x = np.arange(0, 300, 10)
y = np.arange(0, 300, 10)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
xx = xx.ravel()
yy = yy.ravel()
value = np.sin(xx / 50) * np.cos(yy / 50) * 50 + 50
"""

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=xx, y=yy, z=value))

surface = Surface3d(x="x", y="y", z="z", data_source=source)

show(surface)
```

Answer (score 1):

First it must be stated clearly: Bokeh does not have any built-in 3d capability, nor is 3d plotting a priority for the project. The example you linked is, first and foremost, an example of how Bokeh can be *extended* to integrate third party JavaScript libraries. By chance, the library chose for the example was the [vis.js Graph3d library](http://visjs.org/graph3d_examples.html). This is a fairly simplistic 3d library, and as far as I can tell, parametric surfaces are simply beyond its ability. To render this sort of surface would require creating your own new [custom Bokeh extension](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html) that wrapped a more sophisticated 3d JavaScript library (e.g. *three.js*, *vtk.js*, etc).